# Is it possible to do an adequate prediction on tiny sample?

Tags: time-series, small-sample, forecastability

I have a financial time series, `x`, it's length is `n=8` observations only. Each observation corresponds to the quarterly costs (numerical value) of a firm. I need to predict future costs and find 95% confidence interval on the next quarter.

```
x <-    c(1122156.70, 777243.30, 741537.90, 1160976.40, 
        1316723.00, 781010.00, 70447.00, 1413481.00)
plot(x, xlab='Quarters', ylab='Cost, USD')
```

From the plot you can assume in this series that there exists a seasonal component.

My intuition is: to split the quarterly value on the month one, and then apply some method (for example non-linear regression) to predict future costs. For simplicity let's split under assumption of the uniform distibution.
For instance,

```
x1 <-rep(x/3, each=3) # uniform split on 3  
length(x)
#[1] 8
length(x1)
#[1] 24
```

In this case I'll have $n=24$ observations.

Of course you can say it's impossible to do an adequate prediction on such a tiny sample.

**Question.** Could you please share your point of view on the problem?

Comment: Could you clarify what you expect to gain by "splitting" the quarterly data into months? You don't really have 24 *observations* at that point because you really haven't obtained any additional information. The assumption that each month in a seasonal, quarterly financial series is constant is also unlikely to be true, in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I hope to increase a size sample. Uniform splitting is the assumption only. I can split into three unequal terms which sum equals to the quartel value,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work. To convince yourself imagine that you had only a *single* value and repeated it one thousand times to have a sample of one thousand. Would single value repeated one thousand times have any additional information value? Actually many software packages will throw errors when encountering such zero-variance data. You can also check [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162443/making-up-for-a-low-sample-size-by-increasing-the-number-of-observations/162446#162446) that describes similar idea and it's shortcomings.

For learning more about dealing with short time-series check my question and the great answers it received: [Best method for short time-series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135061/best-method-for-short-time-series)